# Table variable column sizes

Tags: html, css, material-design, material-design-lite

I have a table as following:

```
<table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-data-table--selectable mdl-shadow--2dp">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Select</th>
            <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"><input type="number" name="id" [(ngModel)]="filter.id" placeholder="Id"></th>
            <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"><input type="text" name="What" [(ngModel)]="filter.what" placeholder="Title"></th>
            <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"><input type="text" name="how_often" [(ngModel)]="filter.how_often" placeholder="How often"></th>
            <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"><input type="text" name="how_important" [(ngModel)]="filter.how_important" placeholder="How important"></th>

            <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"><input type="text" name="how_imp_improvement" [(ngModel)]="filter.how_imp_improvement" placeholder="How important is improvement"></th>
            <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"><input type="text" name="what_advantage_of_improvement" [(ngModel)]="filter.what_advantage_of_improvement" placeholder="Why important is improvement"></th>

            <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"><input type="number" name="feature" [(ngModel)]="filter.featureId"  placeholder="Feature"></th>
            <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"><input type="number" name="stakeholderId" [(ngModel)]="filter.stakeholderId"  placeholder="Stakeholder"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="9">
                <span style="float: left;"><p>Total tasks: {{numberOfTasks}} </p></span>
                <label for="limit">Limit: </label><input type="number" name="limit" [(ngModel)]="limit" min="1" [attr.max]="[numberOfTasks]" step="1" placeholder="Limit">
                <label for="page">Page: </label><input type="number" name="page" [(ngModel)]="page" min="1" [attr.max]="[numberOfTasks]" step="1" placeholder="Page">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let task of tasks | taskfilter:filter | slice:(page-1)*limit:page*limit" (click)="openTask(task)">
            <td><input *ngIf="!task.featureId" type="checkbox" [ngModel]="checkboxValue" (ngModelChange)="addToFeature($event, task)" ></td>
            <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{task.taskId}}</td>
            <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{task.what}}</td>
            <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{task.how_often}}</td>
            <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{task.how_important}}</td>
            <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{task.how_imp_improvement}}</td>
            <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{task.what_advantage_of_improvement}}</td>
            <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{task.featureId}}</td>
            <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{task.stakeholderId}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And it's css:

```
.mdl-data-table {
    table-layout:fixed;
    width: 100%; 
}
#my-table td, th {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

th,td,input,p,footer,li,label {
    color: #404040;
    font-size: 14px;
}

table thead th, table tfoot td {
    background-color: lightgray;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 4px;
}
table td {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 2px 4px;
}
table input {
    padding: 4px 2px;
}
table input[type=number] {
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 100px;
}
table input[type=text] {
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 95%;
}
```

These settings give me all columns with a fixed width. However few columns can be narrow and few should occupy more width to see contents properly.

For example first two and last two columns could be of less width-just to occupy the contents. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly but, try changing the table layout to auto

```
.mdl-data-table {
    table-layout:auto;
    width: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: Will that make my columns adjustable? as in I can adjust column width?

Comment: Not directly, but you can adjust the width of the content(therefore the width of the column), or use paddings in the cell you want to adjust.